# java.sql.SQLException: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: sqlexception

I have read the articles [Oracle 11g Express error: ORA-12505, TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679921/oracle-11g-express-error-ora-12505-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-si) and [ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753236/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript) , but it did not help. Below is the code, I am using to connect with my D.B using Hibernate.

IVAADMIN

```
    <property name="connection.password">-----</property>

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@GCU13282.austin.hpicorp.net:1526:IVAHPIP</property>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>

    <property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">ivaitaly_oracle_thin_driver</property>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

I am not able to connect with the database with the credentials provided. But I am able to connect with the DB in sqldeveloper. The following exception occurs when I try to UP my application. But, earlier I was using different credentials for connecting to the OTHER D.B and it was working FINE.

NOTE: I have OracleXETNSListener and OracleserviceXE in running mode.

I am getting following exception.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
 TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
 GCU13282.austin.hpicorp.net:1526:IVAHPIP

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the following line of code 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//GCU13282.austin.hpicorp.net:1526/IVAHP‌​IP just added two forward slash in front of host name and one forward slash ahead of the service name and its working FINE now.